# Working with a system of differential equations that cannot be solved explicitly

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, algebraic-manipulation

I have to work a lot with three functions $\;o_1(t), o_2(t), o_3(t)\;$ that are solutions to a certain system of differential equations:

```
Halp = {
  D[o1[t], t] == o1[t]*o2[t] + o1[t]*o3[t] - o2[t]*o3[t], 
  D[o2[t], t] == o1[t]*o2[t] + o2[t]*o3[t] - o1[t]*o3[t],
  D[o3[t], t] == o1[t]*o3[t] + o2[t]*o3[t] - o1[t]*o2[t]}
sol = DSolve[Halp, {o1[t], o2[t], o3[t]}, {t}]
```

The system cannot be solved explicitly with *Mathematica*, but I do not need the solution. What I would like to do is to compute higher order derivatives assuming that $o_1(t)$, $o_2(t)$, and $o_3(t)$ are solutions to the above system.

How could I tell *Mathematica* to do this?

Comment: What higher orders?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are many ways which one could exploit. For example let's use calculate `o1''[t]` eliminating `o1'[t], o2'[t], o3'[t]`. We can use `Eliminate`:

```
#1/.( Eliminate[ Join[ D[Halp, t], Halp], {#2, #3}] //ToRules)&[o1''[t], o2''[t], o3''[t]]
```

> ```
> 2 o1[t] o2[t]^2 + 2 o1[t] o2[t] o3[t] - 2 o2[t]^2 o3[t] + 2 o1[t] o3[t]^2 - 2 o2[t] o3[t]^2
> ```

Changing the order in the square bracket we can calculate `o2''[t]` and `o3''[t]`.

For the third order derivative of e.g. `o1[t]` we can eliminate other dependent variables in many different ways, let's point out one of them:

```
#1 /.( 
Eliminate[ Join[ D[Halp, {t, 2}], D[Halp, t], Halp], {##2}] 
//ToRules) &[o1'''[t], o2'''[t], o3'''[t], o2''[t], o3''[t], o1''[t]]
```

> ```
>   2 o1[t]^2 o2[t]^2 + 4 o1[t] o2[t]^3 - 4 o1[t]^2 o2[t] o3[t] + 8 o1[t] o2[t]^2 o3[t]
> - 4 o2[t]^3 o3[t] + 2 o1[t]^2 o3[t]^2 + 8 o1[t] o2[t] o3[t]^2 - 10 o2[t]^2 o3[t]^2 
> + 4 o1[t] o3[t]^3 - 4 o2[t] o3[t]^3
> ```

In the above we eliminated all dependent variables starting from the second position in the square bracket (note very useful sign `##n` i.e. `SlotSequence` ) and calculated  `o1'''[t]`. Of course you can try to get rid of different dependent variables. In general this is a difficult issue to decide which dependent variables could be eliminated and how they could be represented by another variables. I suggest to take a closer look at `GroebnerBasis` with the `MonomialOrder -> EliminationOrder` option.

```
GroebnerBasis[ polys, vars, elims, MonomialOrder -> EliminationOrder]
```

If given equations are relatively simple you can't observe a common problem in differential elimination - so called intermediate expresssion swell. For interesting mathematical issues related to the problem I'd suggest to study e.g. a recent monograph  *Involution* by *Werner Seiler* (Springer 2009). However I couldn't mention interesting packages in `Mathematica` related to differential elimination (there are such packages e.g. in *Maple*).

Answer (score 4):

I would simply define rules for derivatives of `o1`, `o2` and `o3` and avoid the use of [`Eliminate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eliminate) or [`GroebnerBasis`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroebnerBasis):

```
o1' = Function[t, o1[t]*o2[t]+o1[t]*o3[t]-o2[t]*o3[t]];
o2' = Function[t, o1[t]*o2[t]+o2[t]*o3[t]-o1[t]*o3[t]];
o3' = Function[t, o1[t]*o3[t]+o2[t]*o3[t]-o1[t]*o2[t]];

Derivative[n_?Positive][o1] := simplifyFunction @ Derivative[n-1][o1']
Derivative[n_?Positive][o2] := simplifyFunction @ Derivative[n-1][o2']
Derivative[n_?Positive][o3] := simplifyFunction @ Derivative[n-1][o3']

simplifyFunction[HoldPattern@Function[t_, body_]] := Function[t, Evaluate @ Simplify @ body]
```

Example:

```
o1'''[t]
o2'''[t]
o3'''[t]
```

> 2 o1[t]^2 (o2[t] - o3[t])^2 - 
>    2 o2[t] o3[t] (2 o2[t]^2 + 5 o2[t] o3[t] + 2 o3[t]^2) + 
>    4 o1[t] (o2[t]^3 + 2 o2[t]^2 o3[t] + 2 o2[t] o3[t]^2 + o3[t]^3)
>
> 2 (2 o1[t]^3 (o2[t] - o3[t]) - 2 o1[t] (o2[t] - o3[t])^2 o3[t] + 
>      o2[t] o3[t]^2 (o2[t] + 2 o3[t]) + 
>      o1[t]^2 (o2[t]^2 + 4 o2[t] o3[t] - 5 o3[t]^2))
>
> 2 (-2 o1[t]^3 (o2[t] - o3[t]) - 2 o1[t] o2[t] (o2[t] - o3[t])^2 + 
>      o2[t]^2 o3[t] (2 o2[t] + o3[t]) + 
>      o1[t]^2 (-5 o2[t]^2 + 4 o2[t] o3[t] + o3[t]^2))

Comment: Would you recommend avoiding (if possible) the use of `GroebnerBasis` and `Eliminate` in general (e.g. because of their efficiency), or is it just a neat shortcut which sometimes appear to be useful?  Nonetheless we cannot completely get rid of  `GroebnerBasis` in differential elimination. +1.

Comment: @Artes I'm just saying that for a *system* of equations of the form `y'[t] == f[y[t]]`, where both `y` and `f` are vectors, there is no need to use `Eliminate`.

Comment: Ok, fair enough.