# Variable change

Tags: replacement, variable

If I have the following Hamiltonian:

```
1/2 k q[t]^2 + Derivative[1][q][t] (m Derivative[1][q][t] + y q[t]) - 
1/2 m Derivative[1][q][t]^2 - y q[t] Derivative[1][q][t]
```

and I have for p:

```
p = y q[t] + m Derivative[1][q][t]
```

How can I substitute `p` in order to eliminate `q'[t]`?

Comment: `H /. q'[t] -> (p - y q[t])/m`? But I'm not sure what is the final goal.

Comment: See a closely related problem encountered when one deals with systems of differential equations [Working with a system of differential equations that cannot be solved explicitly](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39504/working-with-a-system-of-differential-equations-that-cannot-be-solved-explicitly/39506#39506)

Comment: I tried but it gaves me: 
`1/2 (k q[t]^2 + m Derivative[1][q][t]^2)`

Comment: This? :`1/2 k q[t]^2 + Derivative[1][q][t] (m Derivative[1][q][t] + y q[t]) - 
  1/2 m Derivative[1][q][t]^2 - y q[t] Derivative[1][q][t] /. 
 q'[t] -> (p - y q[t])/m`

Comment: Thank you, I solved. It didn't work because I previously defined p as:
`p := D[L, {Derivative[1][q][t]}]`

Answer (score 4):

If you aim to exclude the derivative, try this:

```
     1/2 k q[t]^2 + Derivative[1][q][t] (m Derivative[1][q][t] + y q[t]) - 
   1/2 m Derivative[1][q][t]^2 - y q[t] Derivative[1][q][t] /. 
  q'[t] -> p/m - y/m*q[t] // Simplify

(* (p^2 - 2 p y q[t] + (k m + y^2) q[t]^2)/(2 m)  *)
```

If, on the other hand, you aim to exclude the `q[t]`, try this:

```
1/2 k q[t]^2 + Derivative[1][q][t] (m Derivative[1][q][t] + y q[t]) - 
   1/2 m Derivative[1][q][t]^2 - y q[t] Derivative[1][q][t] /. 
  q -> (p - y/m*q'[#] &) // Simplify

(*  (k m^2 p^2 - 2 k m p y Derivative[1][q][t] + 
 k y^2 Derivative[1][q][t]^2 + m y^2 (q^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t]^2)/(2 m^2)   *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: @Kuba It should