# Eliminate functions from system of partial differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, symbolic

Here's the system of PDE

```
Eq1L = (-s^2)*β^2*up[x, y] + Derivative[0, 2][up][x, y] - β^2*Derivative[1, 0][θp][x, y] - 
    Derivative[1, 1][vp][x, y] + β^2*Derivative[1, 1][vp][x, y] + 
    β^2*Derivative[2, 0][up][x, y]; 
Eq2L = (-s^2)*β^2*vp[x, y] - β^2*Derivative[0, 1][θp][x, y] + 
    β^2*Derivative[0, 2][vp][x, y] - Derivative[1, 1][up][x, y] + 
    β^2*Derivative[1, 1][up][x, y] + Derivative[2, 0][vp][x, y]; 
Eq3L = s*ϵ1*ep[x, y] + s^2*ϵ1*τo*ep[x, y] - ϵ2*Qp[x] - s*ϵ2*τo*Qp[x] + s*θp[x, y] + 
    s^2*τo*θp[x, y] - Derivative[0, 2][θp][x, y] - Derivative[2, 0][θp][x, y]; 
Eq4L = -ep[x, y] + Derivative[0, 1][vp][x, y] + Derivative[1, 0][up][x, y]; 
Eq5L = β^2*ep[x, y] - β^2*θp[x, y] - σxp[x, y] - 2*Derivative[0, 1][vp][x, y];
```

How can eliminate `up[x, y]`, `vp[x, y]` and `ep[x, y]` and obtain an equation of fourth order in `θp[x, y]` ?

Comment: I do not receive any error messages from `Eq3L // FullSimplify`.  Save your code and restart Mathematica to see what you then get.

Comment: Also, no variables can be eliminated, because the question contains no equations.

Comment: Thanks bbgodfrey. You mean you got a fourth or a 6th order differential equation in [Theta]p[x,y]?!. If So, would you please send or post the steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Again, this question is very similar to [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39504/1871). And I think it's the original version of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/133966/1871)?

We first eliminate the `ep[x, y]` because there's no derivative of `ep[x, y]` in the system so eliminating the system first will make the analysis simpler:

```
neweq = List @@ 
   Eliminate[{Eq1L == 0, Eq2L == 0, Eq3L == 0, Eq4L == 0, Eq5L == 0}, ep[x, y]] // 
  Simplify
```

Then eliminate `up` and `vp`:

```
Equal @@@ First@
   Solve[Flatten[{neweq, D[neweq[[2]], x], D[neweq[[1]], {x, 2}], D[neweq[[1]], {y, 2}], 
      D[neweq[[3]], {x, 2}], D[neweq[[3]], {y, 2}]}], θp[x, y], {up[x, y], 
     vp[x, y], Derivative[0, 1][vp][x, y], Derivative[1, 0][up][x, y], 
     Derivative[1, 2][up][x, y], 
       Derivative[2, 1][vp][x, y], Derivative[3, 0][up][x, y], 
     Derivative[0, 3][vp][x, y]}] // Simplify
```

Comment: Thanks xzczd.  I will continue the solution by applying the Fourier exponential transform and then Fourier Cos and Sin transform.

Comment: Thank you it is a good solution, I accept it.

Comment: @Essam If you decide to accept this answer, you can [click the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/).