# Eliminate functions from system of ordinary differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic

I have the following system of ODE

```
eq1 = -s^2 ep[x] - cp''[x] + ep''[x] - θp''[x];
eq2 = A cp[x] - B cp''[x] + ep''[x] + C θp''[x];
eq3 = E cp[x] + F cp[x] + s ϵ ep[x] + G ep[x] + s θp[x] + K θp[x] - θp''[x];
```

`A`, `B`, `C`, `E`, `F`, `G` and `K` are constants. I need to eliminate both `ep[x]` and `cp[x]` from the equations so I solved `eq1` and `eq2` and got `ep[x]` and `cp[x]` by:

```
 Solve[eq1 == 0, cp[x]] // Simplify
 Solve[eq2 == 0, cp[x]] // Simplify  
 eq3 // Simplify
```

Then how I can eliminate `cp[x]` and `ep[x]` and their derivatives from `eq3`? Using the substituting `/.` rule will remove `cp[x]` and `ep[x]` but not their derivatives. I should obtain a 6th order differential equation of `θp` only.

Comment: Do you get this error in a fresh *Mathematica* session?

Comment: Do not use `E` as a constant, because it is used in Mathematica as the base of natural logarithms.  In general, it is a good idea not to begin symbols with capital letters.  Finally, I do not obtain any errors when I run your code.

Comment: Thank you bbgodfrey. Most of the constants I used in the original file are in Greek letters. did you eliminate the functions cp[x] and ep[x] between eq1 and eq2?  Did you got a six order differential equation in  θp[x]??

Comment: I just noticed you had done 2 rollbacks and discarded the format improvement by bbgodfrey, may I ask why?

Answer (score 2):

This question is actually very similar to [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39504/1871). It can be solved in the following way:

```
Eliminate[{eq1 == 0, D[eq1, x, x] == 0, eq2 == 0, D[eq2, x, x] == 0, eq3 == 0, 
   D[eq3, x, x] == 0, D[eq3, {x, 4}] == 0}, {cp[x], ep[x], cp''[x], ep''[x], cp''''[x], 
   ep''''[x]}] // Simplify

(*  (s^2 (C (E + F) + B (K + s)) + A (G + K + s (1 + s + ϵ))) 
       θp''[x] + (-1 + B) θp''''''[x] == 
   A s^2 (K + s) θp[x] + (A + E + C E + F + C F + B G + C G - K + B K - 
          s + B s + B s^2 + B s ϵ + C s ϵ) θp''''[x]  *)
```

We can also make use of the hidden syntax of `Solve`. (In many cases it performs better than `Eliminate`):

```
Equal @@@ First@
   Solve[{eq1 == 0, D[eq1, x, x] == 0, eq2 == 0, D[eq2, x, x] == 0, eq3 == 0, 
     D[eq3, x, x] == 0, D[eq3, {x, 4}] == 0}, θp[x], {cp[x], ep[x], cp''[x], 
     ep''[x], cp''''[x], ep''''[x]}] // Simplify
```

Comment: Thank you xzczd. But the kernel hangs when I try the following: '

eq1 = -s^2 ep[x] - (cp^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x] + (ep^\[Prime]\[Prime])[
    x] - (\[Theta]p^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x];
eq2 = s \[Alpha]2 (1 + s \[Tau]) cp[x] - \[Alpha]3 (
     cp^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x] + (ep^\[Prime]\[Prime])[
    x] + \[Alpha]1 (\[Theta]p^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x];
eq3 = s \[Alpha]1 \[Epsilon] cp[x] + 
   s^2 \[Alpha]1 \[Epsilon] \[Tau]o cp[x] + s \[Epsilon] ep[x] + 
   s^2 \[Tau]o ep[x] + s \[Theta]p[x] + 
   s^2 \[Tau]o \[Theta]p[x] - (\[Theta]p^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x];'

Comment: @Essam You need to use **\`** rather than **'** to create code block in comment. As to the new question, check my edit.

Comment: Grateful. it is  working. Appreciate. But actually I don't know how to type code in comment. What you mean by "rather than". Thank you very much.

Comment: @Essam You've mistakenly used two quotation marks. (This is a quotation mark: **'**) The code should be between two backticks (This is a backtick: **\`**, find it in the left-top corner of your keyboard). I've also used backtick when editing your question, if you still don't know how to use it, check how I edit your question.

Comment: Like this code `ep[x] -> (-s \[Alpha]2 cp[x] - 
  s^2 \[Alpha]2 \[Tau] cp[x] - (cp^\[Prime]\[Prime])[
   x] + \[Alpha]3 (cp^\[Prime]\[Prime])[
    x] - (\[Theta]p^\[Prime]\[Prime])[
   x] - \[Alpha]1 (\[Theta]p^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x])/s^2`

Comment: It is OK. Thank you now I know how to type a codes in comment because of your suggestion. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi xzczd. in tn the code `Equal @@@ First@
   Solve[{eq1 == 0, D[eq1, x, x] == 0, eq2 == 0, D[eq2, x, x] == 0, eq3 == 0, 
     D[eq3, x, x] == 0, D[eq3, {x, 4}] == 0}, θp[x], {cp[x], ep[x], cp''[x], 
     ep''[x], cp''''[x], ep''''[x]}] // Simplify`I don't understand the part `D[eq3, {x, 4}] == 0}` ?? Would you please explain it?

Comment: @essam If you mean the `D[…, {x, 4}]` part, it's equivalent to `D[…, x, x, x, x]`. For more information, check the document of `D` carefully.

Comment: I have only 17 reputations. It is not enough to chat.

Comment: @Essam Then just ignore the warning and continue asking in the comment. Also, notice you can edit your comment within 5 minutes after it's posted. BTW, with all due respect, if you put more effort in asking good questions, you should have got enough reputation for chatting.

Comment: Thanks xzczd. I tried the code without the part `Equal @@@ First@' and it gives the same result. What this part is used for?

Comment: @Essam Compare the 2 results carefully, their structures are different, one is a `Rule`, the other is an equation. For more information, check the document carefully, you may also be interested in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/1871). BTW, if you still don't know how to use the document, check [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18606/1871).

Comment: I tried to find the roots of the characteristic equation:`Solve[-a3 + a2 k^2 - a1 k^4 + k^6 == 0, k, Real > 0] // FullSimplify` . I need to remove or exclude those  roots with negative real part. I got a warning message said that "Warning: Real>0 is not a valid domain specification. Assuming it is a variable to eliminate. >>" and another warning message: "Real>0 is not a valid variable. ". I tried to understand the warning but I didn't know how can I avoid these warning. How can we get the required roots? how can I interpret the condition that excludes the roots with negative real part

Comment: I used this but it gives some complex roots:`Assuming[Reals > 0, 
  Solve[a2 k^2 - a1 k^4 + k^6 == a3, k]] // FullSimplify`???

Comment: @Essam This is a completely new question, please post a new question rather than ask this in comment.