# Eliminate equations in list of mixed differential and algebraic equations

Tags: differential-equations

I have a bunch of differential equations (nonlinear and linear) and some equality equations, all are in one cell. I want to use `Mathematica` to substitute the assigned values or variables into differential equations, and finally get a simplified version for them. As a simple example of my case is:

```
equations = {a == b1 + c*x''[t], b2 == d*x''[t] + e*(x[t]-y[t]) + f*(x'[t]-y'[t]),     
    g*y''[t] + e*(y[t] - x[t]) + f*(y'[t] - x'[t]) + m == 0, 
    n*z''[t] == m - R, R == 0, b1 == b2, y[t] == 2*x[t], 
    y'[t] == 2*x'[t], y''[t] == 2*x''[t]}
```

where I want to substitute the equivalent of `y[t]` and its derivatives and apply  `b1=b2` in the main first two equations and finally get a simplified result for `x''[t]` and `z''[t]`.
I tried to use reduce as follows:

```
Reduce[{a == b1 + c*x''[t], b2 == d*x''[t] + e*(x[t]) + f*(x'[t]) , 
  g*y''[t] + e*(y[t] - x[t]) + f*(y'[t] - x'[t]) + m == 0, 
  n*z''[t] == m - R, R == 0, b1 == b2, y[t] == 2*z[t], 
  y'[t] == 2*z'[t], y''[t] == 2*z''[t]}, {x''[t], z''[t]}, {b1, b2,
   y[t], y'[t], y''[t],m}]
```

but, it does not work! it just give an answer for `x''[t]` which is: `(a-e(x[t]-2*z[t])-f*(x'[t]-2*z'[t]))/(d+c)`.

similarly it should give a result for `z''[t]` as `(-R+e*(x[t]-2*z[t])+f*x'[t]-2*z'[t]))/(2*g+n)`

Comment: What do you actually want? You can get a set of reduced conditions by replacing y everywhere using Reduce[equations /. y -> Function[{t}, 2 x[t]]]

Comment: the problem is that I have y[t]=2x[t] in the same cell as the rest of the differential equations, and this definition for y or other variables are changing in each example! so, I can't define it separately the way that you suggested since I have no information of the assigned values in this stage

Comment: Are your constants (a,b,c etc) actually functions of t?

Comment: no, just x, y, z are function of time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a set of equations that you wish to transform to differential equations in x''[t], and z''[t], without some of the other parameters. Solve will do that for you, if you specify the variables correctly:

```
Solve[equations, {x''[t], z''[t], y[t], y'[t], y''[t], b1, b2, m, R}]
```

Similarly you could Eliminate some parameters first

```
Solve[Eliminate[equations, {b1, b2, m, R}], {x''[t], z''[t], y[t],y'[t], y''[t]}]
```

If the variables that need eliminating are consistent across the different cases then that should hopefully work. But I suspect that you want to be able to say `Solve[equations,{x''[t],y''[t],z''[t]}]`, and not have to specify which parameters.

With only 11 free parameters, we can calculate all 330 subsets of 4 and try them all:

```
elimSets = Subsets[Select[Variables[(equations /. Equal -> Subtract)],FreeQ[#, t] &], {4}];
solveSets= Map[Solve[Eliminate[equations, #], {x''[t],z''[t],y[t],y'[t],y''[t]}] &, elimSets]
```

Some number of these may be the correct elimination for how you wish the ODEs to look.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but not really. My question is related to substituting some assigned variables, and simplifying differential equations. I don't want a result for variables of ODE.

Comment: @FaribaRahimi, completely changed my answer, does this help?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but not really it did not help since I get the below results in using solve and eliminiate respectively:
solve:

Solve[{a == b1 + c*x1''[t], 
  b2 == d*x2''[t] + e*(x2[t] - y[t]) + f*(x2'[t] - y'[t]) , 
  g*y''[t] + e*(y[t] - x2[t]) + f*(y'[t] - x2'[t]) + m == 0, 
  n*z''[t] == m - R, b1 == b2, x2[t] == x1[t], x2'[t] == x1'[t], 
  x2''[t] == x1''[t], y[t] == 2*z[t], y'[t] == 2*z'[t], 
  y''[t] == 2*z''[t]}, {x1''[t], z''[t]}, {b1, b2, x2[t], x2'[t], 
  x2''[t], y[t], y'[t], y''[t], m}]

out={{z''[t] -> -((-a + R)/(2 g + n)) - ((c + d) x''1[t])/(2 g + n)}}

Comment: eliminate:
Solve[eliminate[equations, 
   y''[t] == 2*z''[t]}, {b1, b2, x2[t], x2'[t], x2''[t], y[t], y'[t], 
   y''[t], m}], {x1''[t], z''[t]}]

out=Solve[eliminate[{a == b1 + c (x1''[t], b2 == e (x2[t] - y[t]) + f (x2'[t] - y'[t]) +d (x2''[t],m + e (-x2[t] + y[t]) +f (-x2'[t] + y'[t]) +g y''[t] == 0,n z''[t] == m - R, b1 == b2, True,x2'[t] == x1'[t], x2''[t] == (x1''[t], y[t] == 2 z[t],y'[t] == 2 z'[t], y''[t] == 2 z''[t]}, {b1, b2, x2[t],x2'[t], x2''[t], y[t],y'[t], y''[t], m}], {( x1''[t], z[t]}]
it does not give the results that I am after!

Comment: @FaribaRahimi The `eliminate` should be `Eliminate`, remember _Mathematica_ is case-sensitive. And, you forgot to clear the variables. (See the `True` in your code?) Execute ``Clear["`*", Derivative]`` and retry. If you want to know more about why you need to do this, check [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46239/1871).

Comment: Thanks a lot :) it worked this way

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually you're just one step beyond the answer.

```
equations = {a == b1 + c*x''[t], b2 == d*x''[t] + e*(x[t] - y[t]) + f*(x'[t] - y'[t]), 
   g*y''[t] + e*(y[t] - x[t]) + f*(y'[t] - x'[t]) + m == 0, n*z''[t] == m - R, R == 0, 
   b1 == b2, y[t] == 2*x[t], y'[t] == 2*x'[t], y''[t] == 2*x''[t]};

Solve[equations, {x''[t], z''[t]}, {b1, b2, R, y[t], y'[t], y''[t], m}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The key points are:

1. There're 9 equations inside `equations`, but you only need to solve for 2 unknowns, so you need to eliminate 7 of them.
2. `Solve` also owns a hidden syntax similar to `Reduce`.

BTW you may also want to read [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39506/1871).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but these results are not the results that I am getting when solving manually!

Comment: @FaribaRahimi What result did you get manually?

Comment: x1''[t]=(a - e* (x1[t]-2z[t]) - f*(x1'[t]-2z'[t])) / (c+d) 

and

z''[t]=(-R + e* (x1[t]-2z[t]) + f*(x1'[t]-2z'[t])) / (2g+n)

Comment: @FaribaRahimi Just to make sure, your `x1` is the `x` in `equations`, right? Also, why your result still contains `R`? It's `0`, right?

Comment: I solved it by using Solve[Eliminate...], the way explained in previous comment, thanks

Comment: @FaribaRahimi Now you can accept the answer you like by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/) :)