# How to eliminate a variable from coupled ODEs?

Tags: expression-manipulation, core-language

I found this question with an answer:
[How to eliminate variables in ODE?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/171375/how-to-eliminate-variables-in-ode/231144#231144)

```
With[
 {f = 
    Function[t, 
      {x'[t] + x[t]/10 + y[t], x[t] - y'[t] + z[t], x[t] + 3 y[t] - z'[t]}]}, 
 With[{ndiff = Function[{exp, t}, Array[D[exp, {t, #}] &, Length[f[t]] + 1, 0]]}, 
   Eliminate[Join @@ ndiff[f[t], t] == 0, Complement[ndiff[f[t], t] // 
     Variables, ndiff[x[t], t]]]]]
```

I want to know why is this `Array[D[exp, {t, #}] &, Length[f[t]] + 1, 0]` created? If I change the `Length` of the array the solution returns `True`.